# Mongoid migration update fields from String to Timestamp without using Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, moped

I want to update a field of a collection, that actually has a string representation of a date, and change it to an ISODate.

I have a solution already, but It's is inefficient:

```
class MoveTimestampsFromStringToTimestamp < Mongoid::Migration
  def self.up
    self[:stats].find({"timestamp"=>{"$type"=>2}}).each do |stat|
      stat["timestamp"] = DateTime.parse(stat["timestamp"])
      self[:stats].find({_id: stat["_id"]}).update({"$set" => stat})
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to update it in one operation instead of search and update for every record.

Comment: _Sidenote_: since it’s a migration, why would you care about it’s effectiveness?

Comment: Because "stats" has thousand of records and I don't want to affect the performance of the service more than necessary during migration. Thanks.

Comment: Thousand? That said “one thousand” or like? You are wasting your time, thousand of records is nothing, just go with one-by-one. I could imagine somebody worries about 10^9 records, but thousand should be treated as zero.